# dummy.coef() for multivariate models

Tags: r

I was wondering about some things in `dummy.coef()` which converts the estimated parameters (contrasts) in ANOVA models to the original ones. It only works for univariate models, but the changes required to also make it work for multivariate models seem minor. In `dummy.coef.lm()`:

- line 52 `coef <- object$coefficients` would have to be `coef <- as.matrix(object$coefficients)` to accomodate univariate and multivariate models (`coef(object)` is a vector in the 1st case, and a matrix in the 2nd)
- line 60 `ans <- drop(mm[rn == tl[j], keep, drop = FALSE] %*% coef[keep])` would have to be `ans <- drop(mm[rn == tl[j], keep, drop = FALSE] %*% coef[keep, ])` to keep all columns in `coef`
- line 61 `names(ans) <- rnn[rn == tl[j]]` could be `names(ans) <- rep(rnn[rn == tl[j]], ncol(coef))` to give names to the rows of all columns

The printing method would need some changes, but that seems to be it. **Does anybody know why `dummy.coef()` was not designed to handle multivariate models?**

Another thing I stumbled upon: Lines 20-22 are

```
for (i in vars) args[[i]] <- if (nxl[[i]] == 1)
    rep.int(1, nl)
else factor(rep.int(xl[[i]][1L], nl), levels = xl[[i]])
```

Is that safe? I.e., if the `if()` clause is `TRUE`, wouldn't there be an unexpected `else`? I would have expected something like

```
for (i in vars) args[[i]] <- if (nxl[[i]] == 1) {
    rep.int(1, nl)
} else { factor(rep.int(xl[[i]][1L], nl), levels = xl[[i]]) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only addresses your second question (the one about the `if() x else y` statement at lines 20-22 in the code).

To start with, try cut-and-pasting these two blocks into an R session:

```
test <- TRUE

# Block 1 -- Doesn't work
if(test) 
    cat("test is TRUE\n")
    else
    cat("test is FALSE\n")

# Block 2 -- Works
{
if(test) 
    cat("test is TRUE\n")
    else
    cat("test is FALSE\n")
}
```

What's going on?  The `{}` make all the difference here.  Block 1 'read-parse-evaluates' the code line-by-line, causing just the problem you'd expect. Block 2, on the other hand, is read and completely parsed **before** any evaluation takes place.  That's part of what `{}` directs R to do.  When it receives the block of code as a whole, the parser clearly parses the `if() x else y` block as one expression.

The code you quoted was taken from inside the body of a function (i.e. inside of a `{}` pair). In that context, it is handled correctly (i.e. like Block 2).

HTH

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I'd still be very curious about an answre to my first question as well...

Comment: Thanks. RE your first question, I can't think of a reason you shouldn't do it, and since R is open-source, thankfully, you're easily able to. You might also need to make some edits to `print.dummy_coef` to get full functionality, but that shouldn't be too hard either.

Answer (score 1):

We have an [official bug report about `dummy.coef`](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16665)  with a "kind of" patch at which I am looking now -- it seems good, even though changing a bit more things at once than I was expecting.

When I was googling for other problems with `dummy.coef` I got this old SO thread.
Let me answer (as a member of the [R core team](http://www.r-project.org/contributors.html)) that we *are* interested in the extension to multivariate models if the code (and documentation) changes are not large.  Please reply if you are interested in helping.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this! My suggestion is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dwoll/312b44e02071c52ef04b), a quick check in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dwoll/a94b015acaf31ccff37b). Note that this changes the components of the list returned by `dummy.coef.lm()` to always be a matrix. Also, the approach to printing the object in the multivariate case might need more thought. Could/should this be extended to `dummy.coef.aovlist()`? If it suits your workflow better, I can open an official bug report with a patch.

Comment: In the suggested version of `dummy.coef.lm()`, the only modified lines are 71, 78-80 while the suggested version of `print.dummy_coef()` differes more extensively from the original.

Comment: My working version of the dummy.coef.R R source file is already much
changed from the online version, as I have addressed the bug report
mentioned (and linked) above. So I will manually "diff" and apply the
changes as I see it. Thank you also for the example.

Comment: Indeed, I think it makes sense to add an official bug report (without patch though, see above) *or* add to the [existing one][1] with a comment.

    [1]: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16665

Comment: Thanks, I opened a bug report here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16688